# program won't parse splitlines string

Tags: python, arrays, string, split, range

I'm trying to parse a show schedule so I can identify the times certain shows will be on.  I created a relatively effective program when I was parsing a whole string, but when I split it up into lines it started generating a string index out of range error.  I fixed that by reducing the range by 1 and making sure I wasn't checking an index coordinate that didn't exist but now the program is only printing two times.  Here's my code.

```
scheduleLines = schedule.splitlines()
timeCoordinate = -10
for Line in scheduleLines:
    for counter in range(len(Line) - 1):

        if counter <= timeCoordinate:
            continue

        if Line[counter].isdigit() == True:

            if Line[counter + 1] == ":":
                print(Line[counter:counter + 4])
                timeCoordinate = counter + 4
            if counter + 2 < len(Line):
                if Line[counter + 2] == ":":
                    print(Line[counter:counter + 5])
                    timeCoordinate = counter + 5
```

it only prints 9:00 and 8:00 and this is the schedule.  The previous version of the program could extract and print all of the times.  I can't get the schedule to format correctly when I post it to StackoverFlow, but each time plus the name of the show is a different line.

- Monday Feb 12th

  9:00 am - CanDo’s ep9

  9:30 - Storytime ep7

  10:00am Afro Tusk ep3

  11:00a - The Thunderbolt ep1

  12:00 - Seattle here and Now ep27

  1:00p - Startime ep53

  3:00p - heartBeat Radio ep6

  3:30 Single Father ep13p

  4:00p - Traffic Jam

  6:00 - Livin it Up ep 7

  6:30 Sports & Stuff ep15

  7:00 - Lidline Sports

  8:00 - Seattle Sports Weekly ep22

  9:00p - The Reggae ep6

  10:00 -  MoJam Monday ep7

  11:00 Just My Opinion ep21

  Midnight - Diverse Programming

Comment: Can you properly format your sample data?

Comment: I tried to but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to extract all the time from the given string you can do.

```
schedule = """Monday Feb 12th 

9:00 am - CanDo’s ep9 

9:30 - Storytime ep7 

10:00am Afro Tusk ep3 

11:00a - The Thunderbolt ep1 

12:00 - Seattle here and Now ep27 

1:00p - Startime ep53 

3:00p - heartBeat Radio ep6 

3:30 Single Father ep13p 

4:00p - Traffic Jam 

6:00 - Livin it Up ep 7 

6:30 Sports & Stuff ep15 

7:00 - Lidline Sports

8:00 - Seattle Sports Weekly ep22 

9:00p - The Reggae ep6

10:00 - MoJam Monday ep7 

11:00 Just My Opinion ep21 

Midnight - Diverse Programming
"""
scheduleLines = filter(None, schedule.splitlines())
for i in scheduleLines:
    if i[0].isdigit():
        t = i.split()
        print t[0]
```

**Output:**

```
9:00
9:30
10:00am
11:00a
12:00
1:00p
3:00p
3:30
4:00p
6:00
6:30
7:00
8:00
9:00p
10:00
11:00
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but it doesn't quite work with my goal.  I solved the problem with another technique